# React-Router v4 - Browser Router Dynamic Routing

Tags: react-router

I am trying to implement Browser Router with React Router v4. My project url would be 'http://localhost:8080/Project/reactjs/Main.html/SearchProduct' and below is how i set the route path. However i am getting route not found exception. Any help would be appreciated

```
const routers = (<BrowserRouter basename="/Project/reactjs/Main.html">
    <div>
      <ProductScreen/>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>);

render(routers, document.querySelector('.mainContainer'));

In Product Screen :
const ProductScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/add"
        component={AddProduct}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/SearchProduct"
        component={SearchProduct}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you find the way to do it. If so, Please let us know how did you do .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is mostly correct but try removing `exact` from the `Route`s. As the [documentation for `<Route exact ... />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) states:

> When `true`, will only match if the path matches the `location.pathname` *exactly*.

This means the whole path, so not the relative path of `BrowserRouter`. I have had success using `basename` without `exact`, though I didn't test your code.